# Error when upgrading reports in windows forms application

Tags: .net, windows, reporting-services

ReportProcessingException: The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to get an updated ReportViewer control from Nuget Package Manager or simply execute this in your package manager console `Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms -Version 150.1427.0` to install it into your Winforms project.